# use search in "browse oldfiles" list?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to search the list of recently used file in Vim? The list can be displayed using

```
browse old
```

but `/` does not work. I am aware of some plugins (e.g. MRU) but would prefer to not use a plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a short scriptlet that opens the file list in a scratch buffer. As a bonus, it defines a local `<Enter>` mapping to `:edit` the current file. With this, you can search with all built-in commands like `/`:

```
:new +setl\ buftype=nofile | 0put =v:oldfiles | nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :e <C-r>=getline('.')<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. How can I define that as a command? Like browse2? Also, how can I have it take up all of the window? Right now it just takes up the upper half.

Comment: For a command, just prepend `:command! Browse` to it, and put this into your `~/.vimrc`. For full height, use `:99new`.

Comment: How can I make take the new buffer start up at the top (latest files) instead of at the bottom? I tried putting `1G` in various places in your script, but none worked.

Comment: @bongbang: You mean reversing the list in the buffer? For that, add `execute 'g/^/m0' |` before the `nnoremap`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat He means how to make the cursor placed at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: @MImamPratama Ah, that would just be `1 |` before the `nnoremap`. `1G` does not work because it's a _normal mode_ command; we have to use an Ex command like `:[N]`.

Comment: I don't know why but putting `1 |` before the `nnoremap` trigger the "Press ENTER or type command to continue” prompt for me. But it works as expected when I put `| 1` at the end of the line. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to avoid a plugin:

1. `:new` The old files will be printed into this buffer
2. `:redir @X` where X is a temporary register`
3. `:silent echo(v:oldfiles)` 'Silent' is there to not actually print onto your screen
4. `:redir END`
5. `"Xp` paste the temporary register
6. (optional) Do some regex-fu to put each file on its own line.

Put the above into a function and voila. Also `:help redir`

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not very hard to write a simple (simplistic?) MRU command with completion that works like `:edit` or `:split`:

```
" this is our 'main' function: it couldn't be simpler
function! MRU(arg)
    execute 'edit ' . a:arg
endfunction

" the completion function, again it's very simple
function! MRUComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return filter(copy(v:oldfiles), 'v:val =~ a:ArgLead')
endfunction

" the actual command
" it accepts only one argument
" it's set to use the function above for completion
command! -nargs=1 -complete=customlist,MRUComplete MRU call MRU(<f-args>)
```

Comment: Wow, this is really slick and also taught me some Vimscript :) The UI is much better than opening the recent file list in a separate buffer. Definitely deserves more upvotes. Thanks!

Comment: This is really great! So to use it you just `:MRU <tab>`?

Comment: Yes, `:MRU <Tab>` or `:MRU rb<Tab>`. FWIW, [here](https://github.com/romainl/vim-tinyMRU) is a slightly extended version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a .vimrc version of code above. Just add following lines to .vimrc and map to desired keys (in my case it is 'o). In addition define patterns to remove "junk" files. Also cursor is placed at the top for convenience.

Most hard thing is to map an Enter inside nested nmap. ^V is the result of doubled Ctrl-V. ^R is the result of Ctrl-V+Ctrl-R. ^M is the result of Ctrl-V+Enter. You need manually repeat those symbols - not just Copy/Paste. Spent hours to understand this magic - so I'm glad to share. This technology lets you add own macroses in .vimrc.

```
"   Browse Old Files
nnoremap <silent> 'o :enew<CR>:set buftype=nofile<CR>:set nobuflisted<CR>:exe "0put =v:oldfiles"<CR>:nmap <buffer> ^V^V^M :e ^V^V^R=getline('.')^V^V^M^V^V^M<CR>:g/\v(stdout\|nerd\|fugitive)/d<CR>:0<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on Ingo's answer above for my `.vimrc`:

Opens the old files in either a vertical split or tab, then maps enter to open file under cursor! magic!

`" open old files list and map enter to open line
" vertical split
noremap <leader>vv :vnew +setl\ buftype=nofile <bar> 0put =v:oldfiles <bar> nnoremap <lt>buffer> <lt>CR> :e <lt>C-r>=getline('.')<lt>CR><lt>CR><CR><CR>
" in new tab 
noremap <leader>vt :tabnew +setl\ buftype=nofile <bar> 0put =v:oldfiles <bar> nnoremap <lt>buffer> <lt>CR> :e <lt>C-r>=getline('.')<lt>CR><lt>CR <CR><CR>`